# React Native Cannot Request Parse Server

Tags: react-native, parse-server

Im trying to request parse server but im getting XmlRequest failed.
How can i solve this problem ?

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbPk4.png)

[My request code block](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OURQw.png)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the serverURL should be `https://parseapi.back4app.com/`

Comment: I am facing similar error and make sure url is `https` :(

Comment: Code snippet @Shinichi

Comment: I posted this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60235805/how-to-fix-error-xmlhttprequest-failed-on-react-native-with-parse-server-back Thanks !

Comment: @Shinichi Can you show part of the code that initialises parse server with the server url?