# How to fix "Error: XMLHttpRequest failed" on React Native with Parse-Server backend

Tags: react-native, parse-platform, parse-server

Today I have a plan to convert an iOS app (Swift) and Android (Java+Kotlin) to `React Native`.
This app show hospital as Marker on (Google)Maps based on user location.
My backend is `Parser-Server` (now is `ParsePlatform`)

The function bellow query the data (class) from Parse backend:

```
async getHospitalNearbyUser() {
        const { userLocation, region } = this.state
        if ((userLocation.lat !== null) && (userLocation.lng !== null)) {
            const lng = userLocation.lng
            const lat = userLocation.lat
            const radius = 1.0

            let lng_min = lng - radius / Math.abs(Math.cos(this.deg2rad(lat)) * 69)
            let lng_max = lng + radius / Math.abs(Math.cos(this.deg2rad(lat)) * 69)

            let lat_min = lat - (radius / 69)
            let lat_max = lat + (radius / 69)

            // query
            const atm = Parse.Object.extend('Hospital')
            let query = new Parse.Query(atm)
            query.greaterThan("lat", lat_min)
            query.lessThan("lat", lat_max)
            query.greaterThan("lng", lng_min)
            query.lessThan("lng", lng_max)

            query.find()
                .then(function (results) {
                    console.debug(results.length)
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                    // There was an error.
                    console.error(error)
                })
        } else {
            console.debug('no location')
            console.debug(region)
        }
    }
```

However the error shows up is:

```
Error: XMLHttpRequest failed: {"line":169557, "column:32", "sourceURL":"http://localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=ios&dev=true&minifiy=false"
```

I tried to seach on Google and Parse SDK-JS on github issues but no results.

Hope some help from you.

Thanks so much !

// Update:
I am using Parse-Server that is hosted at `Back4App`.

Comment: Developet Tools let you see HTTP requests and responses, which is pretty useful for debugging stuffs like this.

Comment: @Jin-ohKang thanks for your reply. Are you talking about `Chrome "React Native Degugger"` ?

Comment: My apologies, confused with React DOM counterpart. You may find middle-man proxies like Fiddler useful, as long as the API doesn't do certificate pinning...

Comment: I updated question. => I am using Parse-Server that is hosted at `Back4App`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,

I fixed this by changing

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

to

```js
import {AsyncStorage} from 'react-native';
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely an issue with `AsyncStorage` or `https`.

1. Make sure you have imported and set AsyncStorage correctly.

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

...

Parse.setAsyncStorage(AsyncStorage)
Parse.serverURL = 'https://parseapi.back4app.com/'

...
```

Do **NOT** import AsyncStorage from `react-native` like suggested in another reply. This is deprecated and not the proper solution.

2. Make sure you are using `https://...` and not `http://...` for your server url.

Hope this helps.